# How to take care of community dog?

Tags: dogs, adoption, strays

**Scenario**

I live in a college campus, where stray animals are not hurt as compared to outside so even peacocks can be friendly. So there's no question of the dog biting me (I also pet only interested dogs.) Also my hostel room is too small to keep the dog inside or in my sight, so I keep losing the dogs I petted or fed in the past as they wander quite a lot - although they recognise me and get very excited to see me as compared to others standing there. There's no vet inside the campus, but there are some groups working on vaccinating stray dogs and most of them are vaccinated.

**Suggestions required on**

> How to bring them to my room on 1st floor?

Winter has come and it's like 8 to 9 °F (-14 to -12 °C) at night. I don't know where do the dogs go at night. How can I bring them at my room at any time of the day and keep them as regular or permanent visitors? Campus is huge and likewise, they also wander a lot and settle in the most beneficial location, which is not always in my comfort zone

> Should I feel bad about separating a pup from the parents?

As far as I have seen, female dogs normally belong to outside campus and leave after breeding and I have never seen a family together. Also, males just live together for a few months and then babies live on their own. So is there a sentimental perspective I should take care of?

Comment: Thanks, the answer to taking the puppy might be [at this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5702/how-old-should-a-puppy-be-whenever-you-adopt-them)

Comment: Does the hostel allow you to bring animals inside? Or, are you trying to sneak it in to keep it out of the cold?

Comment: @elbrant, the  question is so apt. It’s an advisory to not keep pets inside the hall. But they don’t remove any existing animal out of the hall due to previous incident. Talking about the room, I think I can defend myself by saying that the dog came inside and I didn’t remove it. On a side note, feeding them is allowed in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't put yourself in a position to lose your bed over a pup. Talk to whoever is in charge about the situation. Discuss whether your concerns are about getting the dog out of the cold for a night or two, or if you are planning on "keeping the dog" long term. How it will affect other people who also live there?
There are a lot of things to take into consideration. If you bring this dog inside... it will begin bonding with you and look to you for the things it needs. Every night. Animals are living beings. They become attached and dependent on their people. Are you in a position to give this dog everything it needs? This can be a difficult thing to answer -- especially when your heart is involved. Be honest with yourself. Are you the best person to care for this pup? 
Since you mentioned a group that is vacinating the dogs, is there a way for them to provide shelter for these pups? Does your area have a "foster family organization" for the strays? Or is there an animal group that can get them out of the cold and make sure they are fed? 
That is such an amazing thing, that compasion inside you. Just make sure that you take care of yourself first. Because you can't give that pup a home if you lose the one you're in.

Comment: a security guard said that all dogs will be taken to a huge ground nearby. Tin shades will be given and taps etc to facilitate feeding. I don't know how long it will take to start this programme. I will talk to the vaccination group people to see what they suggest. although they also refrain from giving puppies for adoption to the hostellers for the same reason you said. I will put some boxes and old clothes to prevent cold. Thanks BTW. And just so you know, I will not bring them to the room or anything. Will keep feeding whichever comes to me on my way.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Volunteering for the organization who cares for these dogs would help them more than taking one to your room. Just one hour of work per week is enough to make the lifes of many dogs better.

Comment: I'm so glad that your community is finding a way to help these pups. I agree with @Elmy, give a bit of your time to help them accomplish that. It will help you too, because then you will know they are safe.